# mysql join query - QUERY

Tags: mysql, sql, join

i have two tables one paper and one attempts. What i am trying ot do is to show the list of papers and the attempts made on each paper by a particular candidate

query is

```
SELECT 
  p . * , 
  GROUP_CONCAT( a.attempt_id ORDER BY a.date_time DESC ) AS ATT_ID
FROM papers AS p 
LEFT JOIN attempts AS a ON p.prod_id = a.paper_id 
WHERE (a.user_id =15 OR a.user_id IS NULL) 
GROUP BY p.prod_id
```

The query works partially where it will show all the papers the client has not attempted but it will not show the paper if the client has not attempted but another HAS attempted, so if the attempt of paper 2 has user id 14 in the attempts table and another client has user id  15 who has not attempted paper 2 then paper 2 does not show up on the list ...

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An outer join still gives you records when there are none. With paper 2, there is nothing outer-joined, however, because a record *is* found (for user 14). Later, in your WHERE clause, you remove that record, as you say you only want to keep user 15 or null.

Move the criteria to the ON clause to make it work as desired.

```
SELECT 
  p . * , 
  GROUP_CONCAT( a.attempt_id ORDER BY a.date_time DESC ) AS ATT_ID 
FROM papers AS p 
LEFT JOIN attempts AS a ON p.prod_id = a.paper_id and a.user_id = 15
GROUP BY p.prod_id
```

Comment: thanks it works ... will select this answer once they allow me too